# How to predict two values ahead of a time series using Encog?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, encog

How to predict two values ahead of a time series using Encog?
To predict two values ahead with NN (Encog). is correct create outpute layer with 2 neurons?

```
BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 12));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,  numNeuOcultos));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),false,2)); <-HERE
network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
network.reset();
```

Comment: Encog has better capabilities for time series handling. DataNormalization, TemporalMLDataSet and MarketDataDescription. Look at them. They will do better job for you.